# What would a scrum team member do if he realized that he misunderstood his daily work?

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum

For many years I have been involved in projects which are managed by waterfall or V-model frameworks. For a while I am reading about agile methodologies, mainly scrum, and getting opinions about sprints, daily meetings, burndown charts etc. However all the articles I read describe the methodology when everything goes well.

Last week, I was in an interview and not able to answer a **bad-case** question:

> What if you realize that you misunderstood something about your daily
>   work in a daily morning meeting? Or, you find yourself in a situation that you
>   don't know the requirement of your daily work, what would you do?

I could only say; *I don't know but I would not burn that day out. Maybe to talk to the scrum master and ask to gather the team again?*

What should a scrum developer team member do in such a case?

**EDIT:**

There are many failure scenarios for scrum masters (motivating the team members, communicating with the customer, failure of sprints etc.), but I could not find failure cases for scrum team members.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @ceejayoz when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: It's a good question for [programmers.se] community. [so] is about programming - not time organisation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about project management, not programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You talk to whomever you need to talk to in order to figure out what you should be doing. That might be stakeholder, that might be a member of the team who is an expert on that part of the system, it might be someone else, it might be multiple people.

The daily scrum is an opportunity to get people on the same page. It isn't the only time you are allowed to communicate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, what if this issue effects other participants daily works?

Comment: You're a team, not a bunch of people sitting in silos. If its more productive for a member of the team to help you then it is for them to work one something else while you twiddle your thumbs, then so be it. I refer you back to the last paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ask for help as soon as he knows that the plan he had for the next 24h is void.

Probably first to a co-team-member, if that doesn't yield the answer the product owner, if that doesn't help a user, stakeholder or anyone else. If you can't get access to a person who can help you, signal the scrum master, as this would be an impediment.

Report on your findings at least at the next daily scrum, but of course you can call, send email, drop a message in slack, update the scrum board way before that.

This isn't a failure, it's getting a better understanding of the real problem. As this often leads to new work being found, the Sprint Backlog is updated with new sprint backlog items to reflect the new reality. If the new understanding jeopardizes the sprint goal, I (the developer) 'd personally call for a quick full-team meeting to adjust strategy.

I'd say this falls under this part of the Scrum Guide:

> The Development Team modifies the Sprint Backlog throughout the Sprint, and the Sprint Backlog emerges during the Sprint. This emergence occurs as the Development Team works through the plan and learns more about the work needed to achieve the Sprint Goal.
>
> As new work is required, the Development Team adds it to the Sprint Backlog.
>
> <sup>http://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#artifacts-sprintbacklog</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In General, Product owner and Team member understand the requirement of particular scrum and task list for that scrum.

1.If one member is facing any issue in understanding the task or
   business requirement, you can talk to product owner for more clarification regarding the story/task.

2.If you have understood the task but facing problem in understanding the technical requirement, you should have some quick discussion with another team member after your finding related to the task and fix the blocker of understanding as soon as possible.

3.Report your situation to scrum master if you are not able to make it even after having discussion with team member.

4.have a meeting with multiple members if you still see it a blocker.

Talks and discussion are the solutions for solving any issue in all process including scrum. Scrum is tightly scheduled process, so you have to take quick decision and action to fix understanding blocker.